# Why does linux freeze and not work correctly

Tags: linux, debian, freeze

I moved from Windows to Linux. I have been using Linux for a few weeks. I am having some problems, such as freezing, errors. I am a programmer on the rider program. When I run this program, Linux freezes and I cannot do anything with it.

When I use Bluetooth headphones, there is a delay in the sound and interruption, these things do not happen to me when I was using Windows.
Is there a solution? I am using debian 12.

These are the laptop specifications
[image]

Comment: For bluetooth, you can set a delay in settings of the blueman applet on the desktop.

Comment: What is the rider program and what does it do? If you are one of its developers, then you would be one of the people to ask about freezes in that program.

Comment: rider the .net ide

Comment: FWIW, Rider appears to be a java proprietary application by Jetbrains made available through their repository, just like for example PyCharm is made available for Python IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In general, and specifically to possibly address your Bluetooth audio issues, I would suggest a distro other than Debian stable. Debian stable is, while very stable, quite old in terms of included packages.

I would suggest, as a beginner, you might find Pop!OS, Ubuntu, or Mint to work better for you. These are kept much more up to date and are still regarded as quite stable.

As far as freezing issues, the most common issue is hardware. Some piece of hardware, possibly memory, isn't playing well and may be the root cause of freezing.

Comment: I didn't have the freezing problem in Windows